# Need Some help for AmChart5?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-native, amcharts5

The RenderHTML is not showing the html

**const MyHtmlFile = require('../../index.html');**

```
<RenderHtml
      contentWidth={width}
      source={{
        uri: MyHtmlFile,
        // baseUrl: 'web/',
      }}
      style={{flex: 1}}
      startInLoadingState
      javaScriptEnabled={true}
      domStorageEnabled={true}
      useWebKit
      scalesPageToFit
      scrollEnabled={false}
    />
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, it is not showing index.html